# scipy curve_fit not fitting at all correctly even being supplied with good guess?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to fit an exponentially modified gaussian function to some data. Data provided at top.

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.special import erfc

bins = [-46.82455, -46.41738, -46.01021, -45.60304, -45.19587, -44.7887,  -44.38153,
 -43.97436, -43.56719, -43.16002, -42.75285, -42.34568, -41.93851, -41.53134,
 -41.12417, -40.717,   -40.30983, -39.90266, -39.49549, -39.08832, -38.68115,
 -38.27398, -37.86681, -37.45964, -37.05247, -36.6453,  -36.23813, -35.83096,
 -35.42379, -35.01662, -34.60945, -34.20228, -33.79511, -33.38794, -32.98077,
 -32.5736,  -32.16643, -31.75926, -31.35209, -30.94492, -30.53775, -30.13058,
 -29.72341, -29.31624, -28.90907, -28.5019,  -28.09473, -27.68756, -27.28039,
 -26.87322, -26.46605, -26.05888, -25.65171, -25.24454, -24.83737, -24.4302,
 -24.02303, -23.61586, -23.20869, -22.80152, -22.39435, -21.98718, -21.58001,
 -21.17284, -20.76567, -20.3585,  -19.95133, -19.54416, -19.13699, -18.72982,
 -18.32265, -17.91548, -17.50831, -17.10114, -16.69397, -16.2868,  -15.87963,
 -15.47246, -15.06529, -14.65812, -14.25095, -13.84378, -13.43661, -13.02944,
 -12.62227, -12.2151,  -11.80793, -11.40076, -10.99359, -10.58642, -10.17925,
  -9.77208,  -9.36491,  -8.95774,  -8.55057,  -8.1434,   -7.73623,  -7.32906,
  -6.92189,  -6.51472,  -6.10755,  -5.70038,  -5.29321,  -4.88604,  -4.47887,
  -4.0717,   -3.66453,  -3.25736,  -2.85019,  -2.44302,  -2.03585,  -1.62868,
  -1.22151,  -0.81434,  -0.40717,   0.0,   0.40717,   0.81434,   1.22151,
   1.62868,   2.03585,   2.44302,   2.85019,   3.25736,   3.66453,   4.0717,
   4.47887,   4.88604,   5.29321,   5.70038,   6.10755,   6.51472,   6.92189,
   7.32906,   7.73623,   8.1434,    8.55057,   8.95774,   9.36491,   9.77208,
  10.17925,  10.58642,  10.99359,  11.40076,  11.80793,  12.2151,   12.62227,
  13.02944,  13.43661,  13.84378,  14.25095,  14.65812,  15.06529,  15.47246,
  15.87963,  16.2868,   16.69397,  17.10114,  17.50831,  17.91548,  18.32265,
  18.72982,  19.13699,  19.54416,  19.95133,  20.3585,   20.76567,  21.17284,
  21.58001,  21.98718,  22.39435,  22.80152,  23.20869,  23.61586,  24.02303,
  24.4302,   24.83737,  25.24454,  25.65171,  26.05888,  26.46605,  26.87322,
  27.28039,  27.68756,  28.09473,  28.5019,   28.90907,  29.31624,  29.72341,
  30.13058,  30.53775,  30.94492,  31.35209,  31.75926,  32.16643,  32.5736,
  32.98077,  33.38794,  33.79511,  34.20228,  34.60945,  35.01662,  35.42379,
  35.83096,  36.23813,  36.6453,   37.05247,  37.45964,  37.86681,  38.27398,
  38.68115,  39.08832,  39.49549,  39.90266,  40.30983,  40.717,    41.12417,
  41.53134,  41.93851,  42.34568,  42.75285,  43.16002,  43.56719,  43.97436,
  44.38153,  44.7887,   45.19587,  45.60304,  46.01021,  46.41738]

counts = [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 1.96463654e-03, 9.82318271e-04, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 1.96463654e-03, 9.82318271e-04, 9.82318271e-04,
 7.85854617e-03, 9.82318271e-03, 1.27701375e-02, 1.47347741e-02,
 1.76817289e-02, 2.75049116e-02, 3.14341847e-02, 4.32220039e-02,
 5.79567780e-02, 6.77799607e-02, 9.43025540e-02, 1.29666012e-01,
 1.48330059e-01, 1.87622790e-01, 2.07269155e-01, 2.54420432e-01,
 3.00589391e-01, 3.33005894e-01, 4.03732809e-01, 4.72495088e-01,
 5.22593320e-01, 5.99214145e-01, 6.34577603e-01, 7.04322200e-01,
 8.18271120e-01, 8.58546169e-01, 9.26326130e-01, 9.65618861e-01,
 9.35166994e-01, 9.76424361e-01, 9.39096267e-01, 1.00000000e+00,
 9.67583497e-01, 9.36149312e-01, 9.13555992e-01, 9.38113949e-01,
 8.35952849e-01, 8.31041257e-01, 8.33988212e-01, 7.54420432e-01,
 7.17092338e-01, 6.12966601e-01, 6.22789784e-01, 5.37328094e-01,
 4.76424361e-01, 4.35166994e-01, 3.89980354e-01, 3.53634578e-01,
 3.47740668e-01, 3.51669941e-01, 2.87819253e-01, 2.67190570e-01,
 3.04518664e-01, 2.60314342e-01, 2.70137525e-01, 2.65225933e-01,
 2.65225933e-01, 2.67190570e-01, 3.06483301e-01, 2.72102161e-01,
 2.61296660e-01, 2.57367387e-01, 2.45579568e-01, 2.67190570e-01,
 2.25933202e-01, 2.28880157e-01, 2.21021611e-01, 2.23968566e-01,
 1.95481336e-01, 1.80746562e-01, 1.56188605e-01, 1.53241650e-01,
 1.23772102e-01, 1.47347741e-01, 1.26719057e-01, 8.93909627e-02,
 7.17092338e-02, 8.84086444e-02, 6.28683694e-02, 6.97445972e-02,
 6.58153242e-02, 4.61689587e-02, 4.51866405e-02, 4.61689587e-02,
 4.32220039e-02, 4.61689587e-02, 4.22396857e-02, 3.92927308e-02,
 3.43811395e-02, 3.14341847e-02, 2.45579568e-02, 3.53634578e-02,
 2.94695481e-02, 3.53634578e-02, 2.75049116e-02, 2.16110020e-02,
 3.14341847e-02, 3.63457760e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 2.94695481e-02,
 2.35756385e-02, 2.84872299e-02, 2.35756385e-02, 2.55402750e-02,
 2.06286837e-02, 1.86640472e-02, 3.33988212e-02, 1.96463654e-02,
 2.35756385e-02, 1.86640472e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 2.25933202e-02,
 2.45579568e-02, 2.84872299e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 1.96463654e-02,
 1.86640472e-02, 1.76817289e-02, 1.47347741e-02, 1.96463654e-02,
 2.65225933e-02, 2.06286837e-02, 2.45579568e-02, 2.06286837e-02,
 2.35756385e-02, 1.47347741e-02, 2.06286837e-02, 6.87622790e-03,
 1.27701375e-02, 1.86640472e-02, 1.66994106e-02, 2.35756385e-02,
 1.17878193e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 9.82318271e-03, 1.47347741e-02,
 1.08055010e-02, 1.17878193e-02, 1.27701375e-02, 1.27701375e-02,
 1.37524558e-02, 1.08055010e-02, 1.27701375e-02, 5.89390963e-03,
 1.08055010e-02, 9.82318271e-03]

def exp_mod_gauss(x, m, s, l):
    y = 0.5*l*np.exp(0.5*l*(2*m+l*s*s-2*x))*erfc((m+l*s*s-x)/(np.sqrt(2)*s))
    return y
    #l=Lambda, s=Sigma, m=Mu

bins=np.asarray(bins, dtype='float')
counts=np.asarray(counts, dtype='float')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp_mod_gauss, bins, counts, p0=[-3.5,2.8736,0.1548])
fitted_func = exp_mod_gauss(bins, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
#fitted_func = exp_mod_gauss(bins, -3.5, 2.8736, 0.1548) #used for manual example
plt.plot(bins, counts, 'o', markersize=1) #plot actual counts
plt.plot(bins, fitted_func/max(fitted_func), '-') #plot fitted func/scaled
plt.show()
```

If I run the code with the scipy fitting as written I get the following result:
[image: Result with curve_fit]

Which is clearly not very good.

However if I comment out the fitted_func line where the parameters from curve_fit are used and use the ones that I supplied in the initial guess (-3.5, 2.876, 0.1548) then I get the following result:
[image: Result with manual paramaters]

So even if I supply the curve_fit with the initial guess which is basically the answer i'm looking for then it fails. I got the good fitting parameters by basically doing the exact same procedure in Matlab, but I don't want to use Matlab. I want to use Python.

Anyone any idea what's going on here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the fitting needed an additional degree of freedom in the EMG function to work. So that it could scale to the data. If I modify the EMG function to be:

```
def exp_mod_gauss(x, b, m, s, l):
    y = b*(0.5*l*np.exp(0.5*l*(2*m+l*s*s-2*x))*erfc((m+l*s*s-x)/(np.sqrt(2)*s)))
    return y
    #l=Lambda, s=Sigma, m=Mu, #b=scaling
```

So the addition of the b term to scale the peak sorted it. I supply the guess [1,-1,1,0] Now fits a variety of data as I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

From the scatterplots, there appear to be two separate overlapping peaks in the data. Here is a graphical Python fitter using your data and fitting to the sum of two Gaussian peaks, with initial parameter estimates for curve_fit() supplied by scipy's Differential Evolution genetic algorithm module. That module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space, requiring bounds within which to search. In this example those bounds are taken from the maximum an minimum data values, with 0.0 used as the lower bounds for parameters that I suspect should be positive only.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings

bins = [-46.82455, -46.41738, -46.01021, -45.60304, -45.19587, -44.7887,  -44.38153,
 -43.97436, -43.56719, -43.16002, -42.75285, -42.34568, -41.93851, -41.53134,
 -41.12417, -40.717,   -40.30983, -39.90266, -39.49549, -39.08832, -38.68115,
 -38.27398, -37.86681, -37.45964, -37.05247, -36.6453,  -36.23813, -35.83096,
 -35.42379, -35.01662, -34.60945, -34.20228, -33.79511, -33.38794, -32.98077,
 -32.5736,  -32.16643, -31.75926, -31.35209, -30.94492, -30.53775, -30.13058,
 -29.72341, -29.31624, -28.90907, -28.5019,  -28.09473, -27.68756, -27.28039,
 -26.87322, -26.46605, -26.05888, -25.65171, -25.24454, -24.83737, -24.4302,
 -24.02303, -23.61586, -23.20869, -22.80152, -22.39435, -21.98718, -21.58001,
 -21.17284, -20.76567, -20.3585,  -19.95133, -19.54416, -19.13699, -18.72982,
 -18.32265, -17.91548, -17.50831, -17.10114, -16.69397, -16.2868,  -15.87963,
 -15.47246, -15.06529, -14.65812, -14.25095, -13.84378, -13.43661, -13.02944,
 -12.62227, -12.2151,  -11.80793, -11.40076, -10.99359, -10.58642, -10.17925,
  -9.77208,  -9.36491,  -8.95774,  -8.55057,  -8.1434,   -7.73623,  -7.32906,
  -6.92189,  -6.51472,  -6.10755,  -5.70038,  -5.29321,  -4.88604,  -4.47887,
  -4.0717,   -3.66453,  -3.25736,  -2.85019,  -2.44302,  -2.03585,  -1.62868,
  -1.22151,  -0.81434,  -0.40717,   0.0,   0.40717,   0.81434,   1.22151,
   1.62868,   2.03585,   2.44302,   2.85019,   3.25736,   3.66453,   4.0717,
   4.47887,   4.88604,   5.29321,   5.70038,   6.10755,   6.51472,   6.92189,
   7.32906,   7.73623,   8.1434,    8.55057,   8.95774,   9.36491,   9.77208,
  10.17925,  10.58642,  10.99359,  11.40076,  11.80793,  12.2151,   12.62227,
  13.02944,  13.43661,  13.84378,  14.25095,  14.65812,  15.06529,  15.47246,
  15.87963,  16.2868,   16.69397,  17.10114,  17.50831,  17.91548,  18.32265,
  18.72982,  19.13699,  19.54416,  19.95133,  20.3585,   20.76567,  21.17284,
  21.58001,  21.98718,  22.39435,  22.80152,  23.20869,  23.61586,  24.02303,
  24.4302,   24.83737,  25.24454,  25.65171,  26.05888,  26.46605,  26.87322,
  27.28039,  27.68756,  28.09473,  28.5019,   28.90907,  29.31624,  29.72341,
  30.13058,  30.53775,  30.94492,  31.35209,  31.75926,  32.16643,  32.5736,
  32.98077,  33.38794,  33.79511,  34.20228,  34.60945,  35.01662,  35.42379,
  35.83096,  36.23813,  36.6453,   37.05247,  37.45964,  37.86681,  38.27398,
  38.68115,  39.08832,  39.49549,  39.90266,  40.30983,  40.717,    41.12417,
  41.53134,  41.93851,  42.34568,  42.75285,  43.16002,  43.56719,  43.97436,
  44.38153,  44.7887,   45.19587,  45.60304,  46.01021,  46.41738]

counts = [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04,
 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 0.00000000e+00, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
 1.96463654e-03, 9.82318271e-04, 9.82318271e-04, 0.00000000e+00,
 9.82318271e-04, 1.96463654e-03, 9.82318271e-04, 9.82318271e-04,
 7.85854617e-03, 9.82318271e-03, 1.27701375e-02, 1.47347741e-02,
 1.76817289e-02, 2.75049116e-02, 3.14341847e-02, 4.32220039e-02,
 5.79567780e-02, 6.77799607e-02, 9.43025540e-02, 1.29666012e-01,
 1.48330059e-01, 1.87622790e-01, 2.07269155e-01, 2.54420432e-01,
 3.00589391e-01, 3.33005894e-01, 4.03732809e-01, 4.72495088e-01,
 5.22593320e-01, 5.99214145e-01, 6.34577603e-01, 7.04322200e-01,
 8.18271120e-01, 8.58546169e-01, 9.26326130e-01, 9.65618861e-01,
 9.35166994e-01, 9.76424361e-01, 9.39096267e-01, 1.00000000e+00,
 9.67583497e-01, 9.36149312e-01, 9.13555992e-01, 9.38113949e-01,
 8.35952849e-01, 8.31041257e-01, 8.33988212e-01, 7.54420432e-01,
 7.17092338e-01, 6.12966601e-01, 6.22789784e-01, 5.37328094e-01,
 4.76424361e-01, 4.35166994e-01, 3.89980354e-01, 3.53634578e-01,
 3.47740668e-01, 3.51669941e-01, 2.87819253e-01, 2.67190570e-01,
 3.04518664e-01, 2.60314342e-01, 2.70137525e-01, 2.65225933e-01,
 2.65225933e-01, 2.67190570e-01, 3.06483301e-01, 2.72102161e-01,
 2.61296660e-01, 2.57367387e-01, 2.45579568e-01, 2.67190570e-01,
 2.25933202e-01, 2.28880157e-01, 2.21021611e-01, 2.23968566e-01,
 1.95481336e-01, 1.80746562e-01, 1.56188605e-01, 1.53241650e-01,
 1.23772102e-01, 1.47347741e-01, 1.26719057e-01, 8.93909627e-02,
 7.17092338e-02, 8.84086444e-02, 6.28683694e-02, 6.97445972e-02,
 6.58153242e-02, 4.61689587e-02, 4.51866405e-02, 4.61689587e-02,
 4.32220039e-02, 4.61689587e-02, 4.22396857e-02, 3.92927308e-02,
 3.43811395e-02, 3.14341847e-02, 2.45579568e-02, 3.53634578e-02,
 2.94695481e-02, 3.53634578e-02, 2.75049116e-02, 2.16110020e-02,
 3.14341847e-02, 3.63457760e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 2.94695481e-02,
 2.35756385e-02, 2.84872299e-02, 2.35756385e-02, 2.55402750e-02,
 2.06286837e-02, 1.86640472e-02, 3.33988212e-02, 1.96463654e-02,
 2.35756385e-02, 1.86640472e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 2.25933202e-02,
 2.45579568e-02, 2.84872299e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 1.96463654e-02,
 1.86640472e-02, 1.76817289e-02, 1.47347741e-02, 1.96463654e-02,
 2.65225933e-02, 2.06286837e-02, 2.45579568e-02, 2.06286837e-02,
 2.35756385e-02, 1.47347741e-02, 2.06286837e-02, 6.87622790e-03,
 1.27701375e-02, 1.86640472e-02, 1.66994106e-02, 2.35756385e-02,
 1.17878193e-02, 1.96463654e-02, 9.82318271e-03, 1.47347741e-02,
 1.08055010e-02, 1.17878193e-02, 1.27701375e-02, 1.27701375e-02,
 1.37524558e-02, 1.08055010e-02, 1.27701375e-02, 5.89390963e-03,
 1.08055010e-02, 9.82318271e-03]

xData = numpy.array(bins)
yData = numpy.array(counts)


def func(X, a, b, c, f, g, h): # sum of two gaussian peaks
    # a, b, c and f, g, h are the fitted parameters for the two peaks
    return a * numpy.exp(-0.5 * ((X-b)/c)**2)  +  f * numpy.exp(-0.5 * ((X-g)/h)**2)


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    #maxY = max(yData)
    #minY = min(yData)

    parameterBounds = []

    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxX]) # search bounds for a, positive
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxX]) # search bounds for c, positive

    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxX]) # search bounds for f, positive
    parameterBounds.append([minX, maxX]) # search bounds for g
    parameterBounds.append([0.0, maxX]) # search bounds for h, positive

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
fittedParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't really what I was trying to do though. I'm not looking to fit a double Gaussian in this instance. It turns out it was an issue with my EMG function. I will supply an answer below. Thanks for your answer.